# Conversion of DICOM files to STL files

Tags: 3d-models, file-formats

Good morning everyone,

I am developing a consulting job in a clinic of dental CT scans.

This work involves the development of administrative software, and preparing a routine for conversion of tomographic files in DICOM format to STL format. The files in STL format will be used for both visualization and analysis of 3D models, such as printing in 3D printers.

Our problem is just the conversion DICOM to STL.

Has anyone come across this kind of situation? We did not find any documentation or tool for this purpose in our searches and we are really with a gande urgency in the solution.

Advance grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marching cubes algorithm can convert voxel data into a surface mesh. A global threshold to determine the surface in the greyvalues is used. 
This [article](https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/09/11/surface-extraction-creating-a-mesh-from-pixel-data-using-python-and-vtk/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

there is a nice software to do it, a brazilian one, called Invesalius (http://svn.softwarepublico.gov.br/trac/invesalius). Itksnap is probably a better initial choise, since it is more intuitive (http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php).

But anymways, it is not a easy job to do, and probably you will need other softwares to help you clean the mesh, like meshlab or Geomagic.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Yes, invesalius (free software) is the way to go. I was able to export a CT scan a few months back using invesalius to either OBJ or STL format for 3d printing (can't remember which). But i do remember i was then able to open it in Lulzbot's version of Cura (a free 3d printing slicing software). But there are 2 things to keep in mind.

1. The image i was able to export was a huge file.
2. The image i exported had lots of extra junk that i did not want to 3d print, so another software like meshmixer or some other mesh editing software would probably be needed. It's not an easy process, but it can be done for those willing to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is this software that should work: https://www.slicer.org/

If that doesn't cut it, I use this site to convert images to STL: http://www.online-convert.com/

They do have DICOM listed as a supported format, but whether it would convert correctly or not I can't say for sure. I've had varied results.

Answer (score 0):

This software *may* be of some use to you.

Whilst looking into [software/firmware for a Frankensbox FX-800](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/18141/4762), I came across this document [For medical use - Dedicated series 3D printer](http://dedibot.com/file/download/3926bbd3566247d6a80d79dfbff45196), on the Dedibot website, which on page 4 states the following:

> [image: MIR - scanned text]

The relevant part (in text form) is this:

> It can be used to read DICOM format CT/MRI/Micro CT/Micro MRI/Industrial CT images and non-DICOM common image formats BMP/TIFF and so on.