# What are the best DICOM files to print 3D hearts?

Tags: 3d-models

I am working on a project to 3D print (models from) human hearts. I want to know if anyone has done it before using DICOM files.

Comment: This software *may* be of some use to you,  [For medical use - Dedicated series 3D printer](http://dedibot.com/file/download/3926bbd3566247d6a80d79dfbff45196), on the Dedibot website, which on page 4 states the following: [MIR - scanned text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqkw9.png). The relevant part (in text form) is this: *It can be used to read DICOM format CT/MRI/Micro CT/Micro MRI/Industrial CT images and non-DICOM common image formats BMP/TIFF and so on*. See also [Conversion of DICOM files to STL files](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/2736/4762)

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience with VR visualisation of DICOM scans. I can tell you that these kind of scans usually are way too "hazy" to simply be 3D printed. To give you the best images possible you need to make a high-resolution scan of only the heart (smaller region scans make better quality images).
Siemens has had some fantastic result with their new range of scanners.
You also need some kind of software to convert it to a 3D model. This will need to make a pointcloud of the heart, clean up unneeded tissue and then make a polygonal model to be able to print it.

Or maybe did I misunderstand your question... in that case you need to look at turbosquid.com, thingiverse.com or cgtrader.com for example.

Comment: Hi Hacky, is there any way you can share your experience of VR with me. I'm new in the platform and I don't know if we can connect somehow.

Comment: I would love to discuss ideas and share experience with you. There is however no way that users on stack overflow can contact each other personally. Here is an interesting reading about the subject: https://www.andreasjakl.com/visualising-mri-ct-scans-in-mixed-reality-vr-ar-part-1-importing-data/
I suggest you post a new detailed question with the "virtual-reality" tag. (There is no VR stackexchange community)
You can comment here with a link to your new question, so I can assist you.

Comment: Don't leave email addresses - it *could* lead to account suspension/removal. SE is meant to be a repository of knowledge to be shared with everyone, not a site for people to just ask someone else to privately solve their problem for them. Read [Of people posting Email addresses in Stack Overflow Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149935/280335)

Comment: Yeah... I read the meta posts about the pros and cons to allow private messages. An opt-in system would need nice, but hey.. your job is to let us stick to the rules, I can appreciate that.